# Alternate access mapping in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, alternate-access-mapping

Is it possible to configure alternate access mapping in SharePoint Online? If so please share the steps to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in SharePoint online because your tenant is created with a specific name and all the sites will be based on that name.

Your solution would be to create a new tenant and then raise a support ticket to migrate the licenses.

[image]

Reference - [Feature availabilty across SharePoint plans](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx#Feature%20availability%20across%20SharePoint%20standalone%20plans)

User voice - [Add AAM (alternate access mapping) to Sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/11351574-add-aam-alternate-access-mapping-to-sharepoint-o)

Comment: to expand on your answer here it is from microsoft on what is available and not https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/sharepoint-online-it-professional-service-description.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alternate access mapping is not available in SharePoint Online. ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx))

URL of a public website hosted via SharePoint could be changed, but the URL of your private(=internal) site collection can't be changed.